# Can I expand the a compound drawable so that it almost matches the EditText widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I want to put a compound drawable at the bottom of an EditText in a manner that it matches the EditText box width (then, adding some padding to left and right).

Since the EditText components vary in width, I want to know if it is possible to do it without hardcoding the dips.

Answer (score 0):

The way they do it for the EditText is to use a 9 patch png that Android will auto expand for you.